# What is a good App for OSX that locks your Macbook when outside "known" wifi area

Tags: macos, wifi, password

I am looking for an app that locks my Macbook when not connected to a known wifi network. And I am the only one who can manage my known networks: I'm asked for a password to add networks to my "known list".

Who knows a good app for that?

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish with this?  Are you just looking for convenience when you move your MacBook out of its "home zone"?  Or are you hoping it will stop a thief who might lift your MacBook?

Comment: Yes, i want to have this as a protection to my data in case of theft.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**ControlPlane**](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) where you can set up rules based on various criteria.

> ControlPlane supports multiple contexts where a context is defined as a location or activity you are performing.  Using evidence sources you can create a set of rules that tell ControlPlane what context to apply to your environment.  When ControlPlane enters or leaves a context a set of Actions are performed.

Answer (score 1):

1) Well, you can compare the current SSID against a list of all known Wi-Fi networks easily enough:

```
#!/bin/sh 

# This may be 'en1' on computers with a built-in Ethernet port
WIFI_PORT='en0'

SSID=$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | awk -F': ' '/ SSID/{print $NF}')

KNOWN=$(networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks "${WIFI_PORT}" | egrep -v '^Preferred networks on' | sed 's#^   ##g')

echo "$KNOWN" | egrep -q "^${SSID}$"

EXIT="$?"

if [[ "$EXIT" != "0" ]]
then
        echo "$NAME: Unknown network!"

        exit 1
fi

# EOF
```

You can do whatever you want instead of `exit 1` to lock the computer.

You could trigger it using SleepWatcher from http://www.bernhard-baehr.de.

The problem is: then what do you do when you are on a new *friendly* Wi-Fi network that you want to add to your list of known networks?

2) There’s also [Sidekick](http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/) which might be able to help. See http://oomphalot.com/support.html for more.